# Matlab Differentiation

Tags: matlab

I need to write a for loop in matlab to solve a derivative using the forward difference method. The function to derive is 10+15x+20x^2 from 0 to 10 using steps of 0.25. I have tried using

```
h=.25; 
x=[0:h:10]; 
y = 10+15*x+20*x.^2; 
y(1) = 45; size(x)  
for i=2:47,     
       y(i) = y(i-1) + h*(15+40*x); 
end
```

Comment: You did it. So what?
First of all `x` is 41 elements long. Why you put 47 in your loop? Also you should put `x(i)`, not just `x`.

Comment: But in any case this is **not** forward difference -- see [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference). For this to be forward difference you must not use precalculated derivative, only the original function should be used.

Comment: Typo there with the 47. But when I do those changes you tell me it spits out a matrix of [1 41]. Is that what I should expect?

Comment: @Trevor the result should be a matrix, you are finding a numerical derivative which is basically a lookup table that tells you the value of the derivative at each `x` point. If you plot that vector and your original `y` you'll see. Also I would store your new derivative in a vector that is NOT called `y`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do like this, as a start,

```
h=.25; 
x=[0:h:10]; 
y = 10+15*x+20*x.^2; 
diff(y)./diff(x)
```

or, as alternative,

```
syms x;
y = 20.*x.^2 + 15.*x + 10;
dy = diff(y,1);
h=.25; 
xx=[0:h:10];
res = subs(dy,xx);
```